# How to prove A\B = A\(A∩B)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

So, it should be analitical prove, and i don't know how to transform left side set to right. I did it from right to left, but i'm not sure.
My solution from right set to left:
Let $x\in A \setminus (A\cap B)$.
Then $x\in A$ and $x\notin (B\cap A)$.
Then $x\notin A$ or $x\notin B$.
Then $x\in A$ and $x\notin A$ or $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$.
Set $x\in A$ and $x\notin A$ is empty, so we get only $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$, which is $A\setminus B$

Comment: You should write what you've tried so that people can help you

Comment: Can you show us your attempts on trying to solve this question?

Comment: The argument depends on which properties are known for these operations. One way could be $$\begin{align}A\setminus B&=A\setminus((A\cap B)\cup (B\setminus A))\\&=(A\setminus(A\cap B))\cap (A\setminus(B\setminus A))\\&=(A\setminus(A\cap B))\cap A\\&=A\setminus(A\cap B)\end{align}$$

Comment: You need to show some effort… this is not a ‘do my HW for me’ site

Comment: @MarioGonzalez updated question with my solution. I don't know how to turn it backways

Comment: The other inclusion is even trivial, since $A \cap B \subset B$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $A \cap B \subset B$, so $A\setminus B \subset A \setminus (A\cap B)$.

For the reverse inclusion, take $x \in A \setminus (A\cap B)$. Then $x \in A$ and $x \notin A \cap B$, so $x \notin B$. Therefore, $x \in A\setminus B$

Comment: Oh, of course. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.